# sed command that combine two command that are dependant on each other

Tags: linux, shell, sed, editor

I need help with a sed command that copies the line of birthday to standard output, removing all lines that start with an "A".
Suppose my sample.txt file looks like this:

```
A birthday is very much celebrated. 
Today is my birthday.
I can celebrate my birthday. 
A man can do anything.
```

and this is the sample output:

> Today is my birthday.
> I can celebrate my birthday.

So, for the birthday line:

```
sed -n /birthday/p sample.txt
```

and for the removing the lines that starts with "A":

```
sed -n '/^A/!p' sample.txt
```

Now, i am confused on how to combine these two lines so that they can work according to the question.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Okay, i have edited my question now.

Comment: This might help: `sed '/^[^A].*birthday/!d' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [pipe operator](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) `|`. It takes the output of the command one the left and 'pipes' it to the command on the right by connecting STDOUT to STDIN.

So in your case you'd do:

`sed -n /birthday/p sample.txt | sed -n '/^A/!p'`

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, no pipe is required - you can delete lines which begin with "A" before printing those which contain "birthday":

```
sed -n '/^A/d; /birthday/p' file
```

Or use sed's default print action (by not disabling it via the `-n` option): delete lines which do not contain "birthday". Any lines which do not get deleted will be printed to the standard output.

```
sed '/^A/d; /birthday/!d' file
```

Using this method, the order of the addresses could be swapped without affecting the logic: `/birthday/!d; /^A/d` produces the same output.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^A/d;/birthday/!d' file
```

If a line begins with `A` delete it and delete any other lines that do not have birthday.

Or:

```
sed -n '/^[^A].*birthday/p' file
```

Print lines that don't begin with an `A` and contain `birthday`.